# Facebook Callback not being triggered

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to have a Facebook "like" trigger a callback, but it seems to either not work at all or work sporadically.  Here is my code:

LIKE BUTTON HTML

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://flevy.com/powerpoint-plugin" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

CALL BACK JAVASCRIPT

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId:'123456789', status:true, cookie:true, xfbml:true});
    try {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
            deliverEmail();
        });
    } catch (e) {}
};
```

I've also tried just this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    deliverEmail();
});
```

Here is the live version if you want to test it out:
http://flevy.com/powerpoint-plugin

One other question.  I created a Facebook app tied to the URL and am referencing its appID in the code.  Is it necessary to do this--i.e. create a FB app for the page just to embed a "like" button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`edge.create` is fired only when you use xfbml version of like button.

Change

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://flevy.com/powerpoint-plugin" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

to

```
<fb:like href="http://flevy.com/powerpoint-plugin" send="false" layout="box_count" width="50" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  Just tested it out with both versions of the JS callback and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks!  Working great now.